# Replacing a formatted string in MySql

Tags: mysql, regex, string, phpbb

I'm trying to replace all instances of an old BB tag markup in a MySql database with a newer, slightly different one.

The old format is this...

```
[youtube:********]{Video ID}[/youtube:********]
```

Which I would like to replace with this...

```
[youtube:********]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={Video ID}[/youtube:********]
```

Where the *'s are a random string of alpha-numeric characters. So simply `REPLACE(feild, '[youtube:********]', '[youtube:********]http://www.youtube.com?watch?v=` won't do unfortunately.

All the clumsy attempts I've made using `REPLACE()` and `INSTR()` have resulted in nasty things like `[b]Bold Text[/b]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=`

Is there a way to do this kind of pattern replacement in MySql? Possibly with Regular Expressions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you tried?

```
UPDATE table SET Field = REPLACE(Field,']{',']http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={')
```

This would depend if there isnt any other occurences of ']{'

EDIT: You may also want to try:

```
UPDATE table SET Field = LEFT(Field,#) + 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+ 
RIGHT(Field,(Char_Length(Field)-#);
```

Just check the syntax with MYSQl docs. Char_LNEGTH() may need to be LENGTH() - im sure you get the idea

Comment: I tried a more verbose version of that which basically had some some kind of `WHERE INSTR(field, ']') > INSTR(field, '[youtube:') and INSTR(field, ']') < INSTR(field, '[\youtube:)`. It didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: is the numbers of random characters fixed length?

Comment: Yes. As is {Video ID} if that helps. It's a YouTube video ID like such:'NOgU4aJtXF8'. In hindsight I should have represented it in the same way I did the *'s.

Comment: Your suggestion inspired me to produce the following...`UPDATE phpbb_posts 
SET post_text = CONCAT(LEFT(post_text, INSTR(post_text, '[youtube:') + LENGTH('[youtube:--------')), 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=',
                RIGHT(post_text, LENGTH(post_text)+12 - INSTR(post_text, '[/youtube:')))` ...Which worked Nicely. Thank you very much :).